# Full translation of Chofetz Chaim into English?

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, translation, lashon-hara-slander, chofetz-chaim

Can anyone recommend (or does this even exist?) a full translation of the Chofetz Chaim into English? I'm aware of some of the 'lesson-a-day' things but am not sure whether these are full translations of the actual book.

Comment: The blue lesson a day Chofetz Chaim is a direct translation if I recall

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I've seen, the books available at https://chafetzchayim.org/ seem to be a fairly straightforward translation of almost all the works if the Chafetz Chaim.

You can see for yourself if you like the format, as they have full and complete text documents of their work available for anyone to read. Here is the page for their Sefer Chafetz Chaim, scroll down on the page for links to their four Scribd files (one for each volume):  https://chafetzchayim.org/product/sefer-chafetz-chayim-4-volumes/

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I use the [2-vol Heb/Eng Shemirat HaLashon, 2006 by Mazal Elul](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1599757427).  ([Also here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1599757419).)